# How to add fields while creating a node?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am looking for a module which allows a user to create a new field while adding a new node.

Is this possible, or should I resort to comma separated values in a big text area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your content type, Edit the the field, scroll all the way down, and select unlimited for number of values.

[image]

Comment: Seriously ? I feel so dumb now. Or may be I need to get used to Drupal. Thanks a bunch ! :)